# Tables not showing up and migrations not visible after `python manage.py migrate`

Tags: python, django

I'm following the official tutorial on Django and have run `python manage.py migrate` in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial02/ . After this, I'd expect some files to show up in polls/migrations, but there is just an empty `__init__.py` there, and when I run `sqlite3` and type `.tables` or `.schema`, nothing is output. Still, the `python manage.py migrate` command seems successful:

```
$ python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
  Applying auth.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0002_logentry_remove_auto_add... OK
  Applying contenttypes.0002_remove_content_type_name... OK
  Applying auth.0002_alter_permission_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0003_alter_user_email_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0004_alter_user_username_opts... OK
  Applying auth.0005_alter_user_last_login_null... OK
  Applying auth.0006_require_contenttypes_0002... OK
  Applying auth.0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages... OK
  Applying auth.0008_alter_user_username_max_length... OK
  Applying sessions.0001_initial... OK
```

What's going wrong here?

EDIT:

Added `'polls',` to my `INSTALLED_APPS`. Then:

```
$ python manage.py makemigrations
Migrations for 'polls':
  polls/migrations/0001_initial.py
    - Create model Choice
    - Create model Question
    - Add field question to choice
(django) Sahands-MacBook-Pro:mysite sahandzarrinkoub$ python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, polls, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying polls.0001_initial... OK
(django) Sahands-MacBook-Pro:mysite sahandzarrinkoub$ sqlite3
SQLite version 3.16.0 2016-11-04 19:09:39
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
Connected to a transient in-memory database.
Use ".open FILENAME" to reopen on a persistent database.
sqlite> .schema
sqlite>
```

Same problem.

EDIT2: Upon running `python manage.py dbshell`, `.schema` and `.tables` finally produced output.

Comment: Have you ran `python manage.py makemigrations` ?

Comment: Did you add your app into INSTALLED_APP? Also you need to run `manage.py makemigrations` to create migrations file before run `migrate`.

Comment: According to the guide, this isn't necessary

Comment: I'm suspecting the sqlite I'm running in the terminal is not accessing the same database as my `mysite` uses

Comment: try to connect to db by `manage.py dbshell`

Comment: You nailed it Bear Brown, that did the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first, check if your `polls` app exists in your `INSTALLED_APPS` list in `settings.py`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # ...
    'polls',
]
```

And then try to run `makemigrations` before doing `migrate`:

```
$ python manage.py makemigrations
$ python3 manage.py migrate
```

**EDIT:**

Now, as your `polls` table is created in your database, you can access the `sqlite3` client by running [`$ python manage.py dbshell`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#dbshell):

```
$ python manage.py dbshell
sqlite> .schema
```

The difference between running just `sqlite3` and `python manage.py dbshell` is said in the docs:

> `django-admin dbshell`
>
> Runs the command-line client for the database engine specified in your `ENGINE` setting, with the connection parameters specified in your `USER`, `PASSWORD`, etc., settings.

Comment: I did it just now, and it didn't change anything, see my edit

Comment: @Sandi I edited my answer with a possible solution for `.schema`

Comment: Thanks, but still no output from sqlite. `.schema` should show everything, and adding an argument won't make it show something if everything is nothing :/

Comment: @Sandi Instead of doing just `sqlite3`, try running `python manage.py dbshell` and then again execute `.schema`

Comment: Correct! Would you mind explaining what's going on in that command?

Comment: @Sandi I've just edited my answer with the new solution

Answer (score 0):

You might have done something wrong or you might not have. It depends

1. If you have not created any model in models.py file and you have registered you app in settings.py `INSTALLED_APPS`

In this case, you are not doing anything wrong. Django will create a migration in the migrations folder of your app when you have created at least one model and you have register your app in `INSTALLED_APPS`

2. If you have created models but have forgotten to add your app to `INSTALLED_APPS`

In this case, you just have to add your app's name to `INSTALLED_APPS`

Hope this helps

Comment: I have added my app to `INSTALLED_APPS`. I have created models. I see no output from `sqlite>.schema`

Comment: @Sandi What is the output of `.tables`

Comment: `sqlite>.tables` produces nothing

Comment: Can you try opening sqlite3 like this - `sqlite3 <filename>`

Answer (score 0):

Create 'migrations' directory inside your app and create and empty file with name "**init**.py" in it.
Then run makemigrations and migrate commands.

This solved my problems.